# how to compile Intellij IDEA from Source to Executive file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compilation, intellij-idea

i download Intellij Idea 13 (ideaIC-13.tar.gz) from jetbrains.com and i want to install it on ubuntu 13.10.

i'm not prefer to run intellij with terminal commands everytime i wanna use it, it's gonna be great if i can open it like another applications we install from ubuntu software center.

so i searched over the internet and found out i should compile it to .deb file to do that. i tried several ways to compile but i got error every time.

can anyone help me solve this problem?

thanks in advance

edit : 
i tried "Create Desktop Entry" to make shortcut for it, but i got this error.
there is another warning about "native file watcher". how can i solve them?:|

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was my Ubuntu installation or lack of my ubuntu dependencies.
now i use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Intellij Idea Works Properly! i just run the .sh file with bash command.
and Create Desktop Entry worked fine.